# Silverlight with RIA WCF project can't add regular WCF service reference

Tags: wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, ria

I don't know if this is a bug/feature but I need to find a way to make it work.

To recreate, use VS2012, open a new SL5 project with RIA services enabled. Create another project, add a simple WCF service (or a SL enabled WCF) and add a method that accepts or returns a simple object (I have an object with one string property in it). Try and add this as a service reference to your SL project. You'll receive this error, among others, in the warnings:

> Custom tool warning: 
>   No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 5 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor.

and no generated code is actually generated.

I found that if I remove the object from the service method and use a simple string/int/bool instead, the reference is added just fine. Also, if I add the same service to a regular SL app without RIA, everything works like you would expect it to. Once I enable RIA on this app where the service is working, and update the service reference, the generated code is gone again.

I remember this used to work because I had projects that used both RIA and external WCF services. Is this a new VS2012 thing? Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Eyal

Answer (score 7):

I can duplicate the problem, and it only seems to happen if the Silverlight client has the 2 System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client and System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Web assemblies in its referenced assemblies.  And only if it targets SL 5.

I have found 2 workarounds I recommend you try if your situation permits:

1) Change the Silverlight application to target Silverlight 4, not 5, or
2) Right-click the Service Reference and ask to Configure it.
   Click the checkbox to "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies"
   and select all assembles *except* the 2 mentioned above.

This does appear to be a bug related to either SL 5 or VS2012.  I will repost if I find a more satisfactory answer.

Comment: THis actually helped a lot. I didn't know it was Silverlight 5 & VS2012 Bugs until I noticed your suggestion. It was fine with Silverlight 4 when updating Service Reference.

Comment: I had the issue with VS 2015 (2012 worked for me). And I had to completely disable the "Reuse types..." checkbox in order to make it work, just disabling those two assemblies was not enough.
But thanks for your tip, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of silverlight 5 and vs 2012 has some bug. [It can solve itself by restarting the vs2012]

If you look at your ServiceRefrences.ClientConfig will see it is empty.  You need to enter your service refrences manually here. I have attached an example of my config page, you need to change the names accordingly

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService2" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="../Service2.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService2" contract="ServiceReference1.IService2"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService2" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```